# Find ratio of sides in touching pentagon problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, golden-ratio

[image]

I need to find the ratio d/s, I suspect that is the golden ratio because of this:
https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml, but I'm not supposed to use trigonometry

I showed that the length of the longer side in the isoceles triangle in the right triangle is s(2cos(36)) then using similar triangles showed that d/s is (2cos36+1)/(2cos36), but I want to do this without using trigonometry

Comment: Are both pentagons regular???

Comment: @4M4D3U5 M0Z4RT Show us your trying.

Comment: Yes they're both regular

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I showed that the length of the longer side in the isoceles triangle in the right triangle is s(2cos(36))  then using similar triangles showed that d/s is (2cos36+1)/(2cos36), but I want to do this without using trigonometry

Comment: What are the restrictions on 'not using trigonomety'? I would assume they mean not just explicitly calculating s and d using a calculator to evaluate the lengths using the known angles. If you expect the golden ratio you are probably wanting to derive a quadratic equation that has the solution you want. Also it might be worthwhile thinking what cos is in terms of ratios of sides and working with squares of sides in the same way you would derive values of cos 45 and sin 30 etc. All of the trig identities are essentially stating something about ratios of sides which is pyth. Thm in disguise.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be the vertex on the first pentagon connected with $A$ by $d$. Use angle chasing to prove that $AF=AD=FD$. Finally, observe the result of Ptolomey’s Theorem on the quadrilateral $ABDF$ $$ds+s^2=d^2$$
to show that $$\frac{d}{s}=\varphi$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $DE$ be a bisector of $\Delta BCD$.

Thus, $$s=BD=DE=CE,$$ $$CD=CB=d,$$ $$BE=d-s$$ and since $\Delta DBC\sim\Delta BED,$ we obtain
$$\frac{d}{s}=\frac{s}{d-s},$$ which gives $$\frac{d}{s}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}.$$

Comment: Where is E meant to be?

Comment: @4M4D3U5 M0Z4RT On $BC$ of course. See please better my solution.